# ElasticSearch: how can I check the way multiple analyzers split a text into tokens?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm quite new to ElasticSearch, so if I overlook something obvious/basic, please forgive me.

I'm using ElasticSearch and want to see how analyzers applied to an index split a text into tokens. And as far as the result of `GET /my_index/_settings` displays, multiple analyzers are applied to the index, like following:

```
{
   "my_index": {
      "settings": {
          "analysis": {
             "analyzer": {
                "my_ngram_search_analyzer": {},
                "my_ngram_index_analyzer": {},
                "my_kuromoji_search_analyzer": {},
                "my_kuromoji_index_analyzer": {},
             }
          }
      }
   }
}
```

So I tried to analyze a text with multiple analyzers using an array, but it does not work.

```
GET /my_index/_analyze
{
   "text":"本日は晴天なり",
   "analyzer":["my_ngram_search_analyzer","my_kuromoji_search_analyzer"]
}
```

How can I perform this?
I'd appreciate it if you would share some information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) doesn't support analysing a text with multiple analyzers and it works with **just one analyzer**, In the index you can define many analyzers which can be applied to various fields in Elasticsearch index.

You can also not apply multiple index time or search time analysers to a single field in Elasticsearch.

Hope this helps.